# Script working properly on one gameobject, but not on another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates, agent, navmesh

I have a very strange problem.

I created an AI using the navmesh tools and a custom script which keeps assigning a new destination to the navmesh agent once the old destination is reached.

I had to replace the model for this AI (was a capsule before), so I did that, copied almost all components, adjusted a few parameters like agent height etc., and ran it.

The capsule AI does its job properly, but the AI with the correct model clearly doesn't.
**After debugging, I discovered that the List of destinations for the modelled AI consists if Vector3.zero's, while the capsule AI has the correct vector3s in its destination list.**

Here's my AI destination script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class AIMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

private NavMeshAgent _navMeshAgent;                         //reference to the navmesh agent
private MapController _mapControllerScript;                 //reference to the map controller script to access waypoints
private List<Vector3> _wayPoints = new List<Vector3>();
private Vector3 _destination;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    _mapControllerScript = GameObject.Find("Map_01").GetComponent<MapController>();
    SetWayPointLocations();
    _navMeshAgent = this.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

    Debug.Log(_mapControllerScript.ToString());
    Debug.Log(_mapControllerScript.HealthPickUpPositions.ToString());
    Debug.Log(_navMeshAgent);
    Debug.Log(_wayPoints);
    foreach (Vector3 waypoint in _wayPoints)
    {
        Debug.Log(waypoint);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    MoveAroundMap();
}

void MoveAroundMap()
{
    if (_navMeshAgent.transform.position.x == _destination.x &&
        _navMeshAgent.transform.position.z == _destination.z
        || _destination == new Vector3(0, 0, 0)
        )
    {
        Debug.Log("Acquiring new position");
        _destination = _wayPoints[Random.Range(0, _wayPoints.Count-1)];
    }

    _navMeshAgent.SetDestination(_destination);
}

void SetWayPointLocations()
{
    foreach (Vector3 waypoint in _mapControllerScript.HealthPickUpPositions)
    {
        _wayPoints.Add(waypoint);
    }
    foreach (Vector3 waypoint in _mapControllerScript.AmmoPickUpPositions)
    {
        _wayPoints.Add(waypoint);
    }
}
}
```

Here's the console: you can clearly see the coordinates of the capsule AI being correct, while the **coordinates of the broken AI being (0, 0, 0)**.

[image: Console]

Here's the **hierarchy window**: Capsule is the working AI, Character_Piccolo the non-working.

[image: Hierarchy]

Here's the **inspector** of the Capsule, the **working AI**.

[image: Inspector_Capsule]

Here's the **inspector** of the model, the **broken AI**.

[image: Inspector_Broken_Model]

Sorry for making this long, but I wanted to make sure you guys had all the needed information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What field has zeroes, _destination or _wayPoints? Also, in the MapController component, are the pickUpPosition set on Start or Awake? Lastly, I think the problem may be in the if statement inside the MoveArroundMap method. Can you put a log inside that to see if you ever reach there?

Comment: The _wayPoints array has 5 Vector3's being (0,0,0).
Since this is the case, _destination is also (0,0,0), because _destination will hold the value of one of the _wayPoint Vector3's.
The PickUpPositions are set in the Start() of MapController.cs
I have a Debug.Log in the MoveAroundMap method, saying "Acquiring new position". This keeps getting called, since the _destination is (0,0,0).

Comment: Can you try setting the PickUpPositions on the Awake method of MapController?

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver.
That's exactly what made it work, and it's amazing.
I've spent the whole evening on this goddamn bug!
Could you elaborate on what exactly went wrong with my code?
If I may guess: it's the fact that I tried to fill the PickUpPositions in one script, before it existed in the other?
Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: Im gonna write a proper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem - and also the solution - are not in your `AIMovement` script, or in any edit you did while changing from the capsule to you new model, not even in any of the scripts and components you provided in the question. The problem is a subtlety in you `MapController` class that was already there all the time (even before your changes), and the fact that you did not experience this error before is a matter of casuality.

As you said in the comments, you're setting up `HealthPickUpPositions` and `AmmoPickUpPositions` properties of you `MapController` class in its `Start()` method. And you're reading the values of those properties on the `Start()` method of your component class. The thing is: the Start message runs once a gameObject is set on a loaded scene, but **the order in that objects get started** does not depend on your game logic (it depends on the scene hierarchy, prefabs, object instance number and other stuff, whatever...) and **should be considered random**.

In your specific case, the `Start()` of your `AIMovement` is being called before the `Start()` of `MapController`, i.e. before the proper values of the properties being set - hence, all you read are zero-vectors (default values).

Because of that, unity has a similar message named `Awake()` on gameObjects. You also don't know the order in which the objects will be awoken, but you can assure that any `Start()` message will be sent only after all the `Awake()` messages were already been sent. More on this [here](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/awake-and-start), [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/start-vs-awake.41633/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652036/awake-and-start) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html).

**The solution**: Put all internal initialization logic of your classes in the Awake method; and all the connections to other gameobjects (that assume they are initialized) on the Start method.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.
I filled the array in the start function of one class, while I put a reference to it in the start function of the other class, without knowing which start function gets called first.
Very well explained, thanks a lot.

One last question though: are there any drawbacks to using the Awake method in ALL of my classes ALL the time to initialize ALL variables of those classes?
I want to prevent this from happening in the future, but not at the cost of bad coding practice.

Comment: Yes, there is one gotcha: you should not try to inquire or get state from other classes from inside Awake - you don't know if they are initialized already (you can at most reference other gameObjects, like getComponent and stuff, but not their fields or methods). General rule is: Set yourself up on Awake and relate to other classes on Start.